# How to make a dynamic list of sections

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents

I am trying to make a document that has a large amount of sections which describe tasks. I would like to mark several of the sections as "high priority" with some kind of label, and then build up a table of contents which lists only the sections marked with this label. What is the best way to go about doing this in LaTeX?

Comment: Are you interested in having a "standard ToC" *with* your "high priority ToC", or is it *just* the latter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is a mockup of what you might be after.

It provides a new "List of High Priority Sections" (as defined in `\highpriorityname`) by using `\listofhpsection` that prints all the starred sections in your document. New "List of"'s are possible by means of the [`tocloft` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft). Each of the starred sections are also included, with number, in the regular `\tableofcontents`. This is done by a redefinition of the regular `\section` command using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse). Additionally, as an in-line marking mechanism, each section of "high priority" will have an asterisk in the form of `\star` added to the end.

So, in short, `\section*` commands will be typeset using the traditional `section` counter/number with an appended `\star`, but it will also be included in the new list of "high priority" sections. Sections issued using `\section` will be typeset in the traditional way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{letltxmacro}% http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro
\newcommand{\highpriorityname}{List of High Priority Sections}
\newlistof{hpsection}{hps}{\highpriorityname}

\begin{document}
% ================ FRONTMATTER ================
\tableofcontents
\listofhpsection

% ================ REDEFINTION ================
\LetLtxMacro{\oldsection}{\section}% Store old \section macro
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
  \setcounter{hpsection}{\value{section}}% Copy section counter
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\refstepcounter{hpsection}%
     \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
       {\oldsection[#3]{#3$^\star$}\addcontentsline{hps}{section}{\numberline{\thehpsection} #3}}% starred section \section*{<title>}
       {\oldsection[#2]{#3$^\star$}\addcontentsline{hps}{section}{\numberline{\thehpsection} #2}}% starred section \section*[<ToC>]{<title>}
    }%
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}%
       {\oldsection{#3}}% unstarred section \section{<title>}
       {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}% unstarred section \section[<ToC>]{<title>}
    }%
}

% ================ MAINMATTER ================
\section{First section} \lipsum[1-2]
\section*{Second section} \lipsum[3-4]
\section{Third section} \lipsum[5-6]
\section*{Fourth section} \lipsum[7-8]
\section*{Fifth section} \lipsum[9-10]
\section{Final section} \lipsum[11-12]
\end{document}
```

The document structure is such that the sectional redefinition happens *between* `FRONTMATTER` and `MAINMATTER`. Otherwise `Contents` and `List of High Priority Sections` would also be numbered sections.

Saving of the original `\section` command is done using the [`letltxmacro` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro), while [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provides dummy text.

Comment: Wow this is excellent. Thank you for the help!

Comment: One remark for the example: when you replace lipsum with blindtext you could use `\blinddocument` (or `\Blinddocument` for a large version) to get dummy text _including_ section headings. Disadvantage: you need also babel.